# Scala/Jerkson: Specifying the format of Date objects in Json

Tags: java, json, scala, datetime, jackson

I am serializing an object containing a `Date` using the [Jerkson Json library](https://github.com/codahale/jerkson) (wrapper for [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome)):

```
import com.codahale.jerkson.Json
import java.util.Date

case class JTest(
    val dTest: Date
)

val jt = new JTest(new Date())
println(Json.generate(jt))
```

Which results in:

```
{"dTest":1353576079168}
```

**Is there any way I can specify the format or override the generating function?**

I realize that Json doesn't have a proper Date type, so the output (unix time in millis) is "correct". I'd like to have my Dates serialized as strings in the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (with time/timezone) format: `2007-04-05T01:12:22+0100`, as it's easily parsed and human readable. `Date`'s toString spits out `Thu Nov 22 10:27:54 CET 2012`.

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html to convert date into a string of desired format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here. Firstly, the minor issue of ISO8601 dates - these are achievable using SimpleDateFormat, e.g.

```
import java.text._
import java.util._
val d1 = new Date()
val sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
println(sdf.format(d1))
```

The formatter will parse as well as format. Remember not to share it between threads (instead always create an instance in local scope before use) because it isn't thread-safe.

Secondly, the more tricky issue of using dates automatically in Jerkson. This appears to be one feature of Jerkson that is inferior to Lift-json. The latter allows custom parser/formatter code to be inserted into the parsing layer. Jerkson does not, I think.

We got round this limitation simply by ignoring it. We like the superior performance of Jerkson, so we just use Long and String for our date transmission and we deal with the parsing separately. For example

```
case class JTest(val dTest: String) {
  lazy val dTestDate: Date = {
    val sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
    sdf.parse(dTest)
  }
}
```

Comment: Clever workaround, however, it creates some other issues for me. My models are also used as db schema (squeryl), and the fields must be "Date" to map correctly. I found that Jerkson supports a "@transient" annotation, which omits it from the json. Squeryl supports "@Transient", which does the same for persistance. If i could find a way to rename the vals (when mapped to json), I could make a "transparent" workaround..

Comment: The 'other' workaround I didn't mention above is to write pairs of case classes. One version supports Jerkson and the other Squeryl (or any other usage). The latter can have an adapter 'apply()' method to construct it from the former, and maybe vice versa. This takes twice as much code, but allows the Jerkson version to be considered as a short-lived data transfer object.

Comment: I like the idea, and I'll try it out. I'll keep searching for a way to do it "properly", but I'm not very optimistic, so I'll probably end up with one or more of the workarounds. Thank you for the suggestions, and please let me know if you figure something out!